# Asus P5Q Pro - hard drive shows up in BIOS but not in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata

I have Windows 10 installed on an SSD connected to one of the two SATA 6G ports. All SATA 3G ports are used up by hard drives. I'd like to add another hard drive, but when I plug it into the remaining SATA 6G port, it isn't recognized in Windows. I checked the BIOS and it recognizes the drive there just fine.

I've tried plugging that drive into one of the SATA 3G ports and Windows sees it just fine. I initially thought it was a driver issue, but I do have all drivers for that motherboard installed and the SSD is recognized just fine.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Open Disk Management. You probably need to give it a drive letter and format it. Admin Tools., Computer management.

Comment: I forgot to mention: it doesn't show up in Disk Management.

Comment: Before you can see the disk, it must be initialized. Use Live-CD with any program for working with disks and partitions (Acronis Disk Director, Paragon Partition Manager, GParted, etc.)

Comment: I've tried plugging that drive into one of the SATA 3G ports and Windows sees it just fine.

Comment: Do you have any M.2 chips installed? they usually use one of your SATA lanes, so you would need to consult your mobo manual to determine which ports you can use with mixing with M.2.

Comment: No M2. All SATA